# SUMIF formula doesn't give the correct answer in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this SUMIF formula but it gives me a wrong output. Can anybody help me? I have checked a lot of times but unable to find the mistake! Thanks in advance!

```
Range("B10", Range("B10").Offset(0, -1).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1)).Formula = _
"=SUMIF('[" & Dest_name & "]Cu Part PVO L'!$M$10:$M$2000,A10," & _
"'[" & Dest_name & "]Cu Part PVO L'!$AD$10:$AD$2000)"
[Output][1]
```

Comment: What output does it get, and what output do you expect? Can you please detail a little more, and possibly include more info such as what is `Dest_name`?

Comment: @BruceWayne Dest_name is the file name from which I'm wishing to import the data and I have declared it as a workbook since it can be any random workbook with the same excel report layout. And I am comparing the Supplier nos and if the criteria is matched only then it has to copy the value of the material but it copies the wrong value and I see some other value in the original file.

Comment: Since it's a `SUMIF` is it possible that there are multiple supplier numbers that are in the `Dest_name` file that you are not aware. So it's adding a few together to get the number?

Comment: Is the `Dest_name` workbook open?  For a SUMIF to work it needs to be open - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/260415.  Also is the correct worksheet active?  This part of the command `Range("B10", Range("B10").Offset(0, -1).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1)).Formula` refers to the currently active sheet rather than any specific sheet.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Ya of course its possible. But I have cross-checked the Dest_name file and the mistake is not for a single supplier no but all the suppliers

Comment: @Neha - yes, so its possible that all suppliers have multiple entries? (maybe it's not the case, but I am just checking. Your formula looks solid at face value....  Are you sure that `A10` holds the right supplier no to evaluate when you formula is placed in the row after the last row of data in column A? (And what happens when you simply enter the formula manually in Excel - perhaps you don't have the exact right arguments in your code as you think.

Comment: Have you tried a macro only approach (i.e. don't use in sheet formulas, but rather calculate the value in the VBA and simply apply the result)? If you try coding up that same logic fully in VBA, it could help to ID the problem since you'll be able to step through the calculation.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I have cleared the formulas after the values are filled and so i think its ok even after closing the workbook. And I have checked, the correct workbook is active. :(

Comment: @JMichael I'm sorry but I did not understand what you are trying to say!

Comment: In your first comment you said `Dest_name` is declared as a workbook.  As in `Set Dest_name = Workbooks("Book2")` for example? If so then you must use `Dest_name.name` within the formula.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman It doesn't give the correct output even when i enter the formula in excel. Now I'm getting more and more confused!

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Since I'm using thie code below, it has to take the name of the file opened and then extract the desired data from the same
    ´filetoopen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*")
    If filetoopen <> False Then
    MsgBox "Selected file: " & filetoopen
    ElseIf filetoopen = False Then
    Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If´

Comment: Can  you update your question with the full code you're using - your example in your comment uses `filetoopen` to get the filename, which I guess you put into the `Dest_name` variable at some point.  We're just guessing at the moment - all I can say is the structure of your formula works.

Comment: @Neha - take the time to get the formula correct and working in Excel first, then translate it back to VBA. I am sure its something small that you cannot see at the moment, but will be able to very soon. If you post screenshots of data in the file being opened and the ids on the sheet with the formula, we may be able to spot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify my VBA only approach here's a rough out:

```
Dim i as Long
DIM wb as Workbook
SET wb = Applications.Workbooks.Open(Dest_Name) 'Dest_name would need to be the full file
    'path, i.e. C:\<Folder 1>\<Folder 2>\....\<File Name>.<file extension>
Dim CPPL as Worksheet
Set CPPL = Workbooks(Dest_Name).Worksheets("Cu Part PVO L")
Dim v as String 'change the type based on what's in A10
v = Range("A10").Value
Dim t as long

i = 10
Do While i < 2001
    If CPPL.Range("M" & i).value = v THen
        t = t + CPPL.Range("AD" & i).value
    End if
    i = i + 1
Loop

Range("B10", Range("B10").Offset(0, -1).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1)).Value = t
```

As an added bonus, this way, if Dest_Name isn't open the values will still display instead of erroring.